# How to see which URLs are blocked by Privoxy

Tags: networking, logs, privoxy

I want to see a log of which URLs are blocked by Privoxy, but I cannot find this anywhere.

Relevant lines in my configuration file (`/usr/local/var/log/privoxy/logfile`) are as follows:

```
confdir /usr/local/etc/privoxy
logdir /usr/local/var/log/privoxy
logfile logfile
```

The log file `/usr/local/var/log/privoxy/logfile` is empty.

Are blocked URLs logged in another file? Or how do I turn logging of blocked URLs on?

Comment: What about permissions? Are these files writable by privoxy user under which the service usually runs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to http://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/config.html#LOGDIR, the log file should be in `/var/log/privoxy`. However, you have `/usr/local/var/log/privoxy/`.

Then, the details captured by the log file depend on the debugging options:

```
  debug     1 # Log the destination for each request Privoxy let through. See also debug 1024.
  debug     2 # show each connection status
  debug     4 # show I/O status
  debug     8 # show header parsing
  debug    16 # log all data written to the network
  debug    32 # debug force feature
  debug    64 # debug regular expression filters
  debug   128 # debug redirects
  debug   256 # debug GIF de-animation
  debug   512 # Common Log Format
  debug  1024 # Log the destination for requests Privoxy didn't let through, and the reason why.
  debug  2048 # CGI user interface
  debug  4096 # Startup banner and warnings.
  debug  8192 # Non-fatal errors
  debug 32768 # log all data read from the network
  debug 65536 # Log the applying actions
```

Enabling `debug` 1024 should give you what you want.

Comment: Enabling debug 1024 was just the thing!